# Creating a gem for shared stylesheets and using it in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, stylesheet, sass

I'm trying to create a gem to put all my common stylesheets in. I can't to figure out how to import the stylesheets in a Rails application. Here's what I've done so far (following [this guide](http://www.zurb.com/article/814/yetify-your-rails-new-foundation-gem-and-)):

1. I ran `bundle gem apple_core`.
2. I modified apple_core.rb to contain a rails engine class like so:

   ```
   require "apple_core/version"

   module AppleCore
     class Engine < Rails::Engine
     end
   end
   ```
3. I created the apple_core stylesheets directory using `mkdir -p lib/apple_core/app/assets/stylesheets/apple_core`.
4. I created an index file inside the apple_core stylesheets directory and added the following to it:

   ```
   /*
    *= require_self
    *= require_tree .
    */
   ```
5. I made a test.css.scss file in the same directory and added:

   ```
   a
   {
     color: red;
   }
   ```
6. I created a GitHub repository for the gem and pushed it.
7. In my Rails application, I added the gem to my Gemfile in the assets group.
8. I ran `bundle install`.

I tried to include my gem in one of my files using `@import "apple_core";`, but when I attempted to load the page I received a `couldn't find file 'apple_core'` error. What am I missing here?

Comment: move `lib/apple_core/app/assets/stylesheets/apple_core` in `vendor/apple_core/app/assets/stylesheets/apple_core`

Comment: What kind of file is the one where you say `@import "apple_core"`?

Comment: @mosch It's a scss file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to mirror the directories in your gem as they are in a rails project. So you can put assets to `app/assets`, `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets`. You then have to make sure that these files are included in your gemspec, for example:

```
  s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib,vendor}/**/*"] + ["MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "Readme.md"]
```

So the Path should then be `vendor/assets/stylesheets/apple_core`.

Comment: I thought the purpose of the engine file was that Rails would treat the assets as part of the current application.

Comment: It does. You still have to tell which files in your gems directory have to be included with the gem, this has nothing to do with rails yet. If you don't include the files, the engine can't treat them in any way.

Plus: the path you've used in your example is not a valid (by default) assets path. They all reside in `{app,lib,vendor}/assets`.